# «Купить билет, не выходя из терминала аэропорта». Стоит ли ставить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, деепричастный-оборот

«Купить билет, не выходя из терминала аэропорта». Стоит ли ставить запятую? Или здесь, как «не выходя из дома»?

Comment: @М_Г Мне кажется, что троеточие должно быть внутри кавычек. А как Вы считаете?

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова По-моему, оно и вовсе лишнее.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Троеточие убрал, а насчет точки не уверен: выносить ее за кавычки или нет.

Comment: В конце фразы после закрывающих цитату кавычек ставят точку, если перед закрывающими кавычками нет никаких знаков.Точка всегда ставится после закрывающих кавычек, но не перед ними. Многоточие, вопросительный и восклицательный знак ставятся перед закрывающими кавычками. http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/54-rubric-76

Answer (score 2):

А почему не ставить-то?! Нормальный ("классический") деепричастный оборот. Ставим. Стоит того.

А по поводу выхода из дома дан [ответ справочной службы русского языка](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=218345&v=full):

> Запятая не требуется, если оборот "не выходя из дома" употребляется не
>   в глагольном значении, а в значении наречия "дома" ("дома вы можете
>   найти...").

**[Вопрос № 215659](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=215659)**

> Добрый день! Подскажите, пожалуйста, следует ли выделять запятыми
>   оборот "не выходя из дома" в предложении: Сохраним природу(,) не
>   выходя из дому. Спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Да, запятые нужны.

---

[Вопрос № 215237](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=215237)

> Здравствуйте, нужна ли запятая: ...можно наслаждаться процедурами (,)
>   не выходя из дома. Спасибо.

**Ответ справочной службы русского языка**

> Запятая нужна.

Answer (score 2):

*Стоит ли ставить запятую?* Стоит. Это обычный [**деепричастный оборот**](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/), который по правилам необходимо обособлять. Вот некоторые похожие предложения.

1. Капсульные отели в мировых аэропортах: как отдохнуть, **не выходя из транзитной зоны.**
2. Появится возможность увеличить обслуживание транзитных пассажиров, поскольку пассажиры из Азии смогут в Риге, **не выходя из терминала**, пересесть на европейские рейсы.
3. … расположение автостанции удобно и доступно. Прилетевший пассажир легко найдет ее, **не выходя из аэропорта**.